# C# MS ClearView access a property directly by another property's value

Tags: c#, clearscript

I am making a scripting program using MS ClearScript.
I would like to be able to reference to a property indirectly without having to type out the value member of my class.

Here is my class:

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class TagIO
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I create a collection and add the hostobjects to the scriptengine as the following:

```
ObservableCollection<TagIO> InputCollection = new ObservableCollection<TagIO>();

foreach (var InputTag in InputCollection)
{
   if (InputTag != null)
     scriptEngine.AddHostObject(InputTag.name, InputTag);
}
```

I can run a script with the following line:

```
a.value = b.value;
```

But I would like to improve this so that I can do the following:

```
a = b;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `AddHostObject`, do this:

```
scriptEngine.Script[InputTag.name] = InputTag;
```

Comment: That works. Thanks. Just having an issue with changing a hostObject directly from the scriptengine. I am Manually setting the Tag to the engine's value:   OutputTag = .Engine.Script[Output name];